# hola , estoy haciendo una carta para restaurante

Tags: mongodb

Estoy haciendo una carta para restaurante la cual pues tiene varios menu por su categoría, por ejemplo categoría hamburguesa, menu : hamb de carne, hamb de pollo, hamb mixta,etc, ,categoria ensalada, menu: ensalada rusa, ensalada de frutas etc, entonces nose como debería ser el camino correcto para  crear el modelo o esquema con mongodb , la información sera enviada desde un formulario, pero mi idea es hacer que cada carta pertenece a un usuario(cada usuario seria un restaurante).

Yo estaba pensando en hacer un modelo con algún campo tipo objeto, o hacerlo por esquemas separados, soy nuevo y lo poco que se, lo he aprendido de manera autodidacta, si me pueden ayudar lo agradeceria mucho.

Quiero hacer el modelo de esta manera:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const cartaschema = new Schema({
    nombrecategoria : {type: String, required: true,
          menu:{ 
             nombremenu : String, 
             descripcion : String, 
             precio:Number,  
             precioenvio: Number,
             date :Date,
             }

 },
 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('carta', cartaschema)
```

Al momento de guardar los datos enviados desde un formulario lo trato de guardar así:

```
router.post('/home/menu-enviado',async (req,res)=>{
   const {nombrecategoria,nombremenu,descripcion,precio,precioenvio}= req.body;
```

Para crear el objeto del modelo, teniendo en cuenta que tengo un objeto anidado, ¿me podrían ayudar en la sintaxis?. Es que busco tutoriales y todos crean el modelo básico y quisiera hacerlo de la manera de modelo con objetos anidados.

Comment: Hola Juan. Un placer saludarte. Lo recomendable es que inicies a desarrollar tu proyecto y muestres tus avances hasta donde encuentres algún inconveniente que no logres resolver. Este es un foro de preguntas y respuestas donde no se resuelven tareas.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Lamentablemente, tu pregunta se basa en opiniones, lo cual es motivo de cierre. En cuanto a tu duda, el modelo de datos se debe ajustar a tus necesidades. Puede ser normalizado o no. Todo va a depender de qué hagas con los datos.

Comment: hola Ernesto gracias, no estoy pidiendo que me resuelvan, solo queria un consejo de por donde podria empezar.

Comment: gracias Mauricio lo tendre en cuenta.

Comment: Diría que te falta agregar la etiqueta del lenguaje en el que pretendes hacer el insert. Ese en el que está el `router.post`

Comment: Pon en el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. No olvides además que las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). Delimita tu pregunta a un problema concreto. Lee [ask].